# Calling QuantLib from R through Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, quantlib

**Preliminary steps**

[**QuantLib**](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) was installed along with [**Boost**](http://www.boost.org/) and built following [**these**](http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml) instructions in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010; test code went on with no issues.

Using R with the following sample code gave the expected results:

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
  int add(int x, int y, int z) {
    int sum = x + y + z;
    return sum;
  }'
)

add(1, 2, 3)
# > add(1, 2, 3)
# [1] 6
```

As of the use of separate C++ files, the example below

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Below is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar)

// For more on using Rcpp click the Help button on the editor toolbar

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int timesTwo(int x) {
   return x * 2;
}
```

succeded for the result in `R` was

```
> timesTwo(7)
[1] 14
```

I guess that everything is fine.

**My question**

If my setup is correct, my question is: assuming my `QuantLib-vc100-mt-gd.lib` object file library is in `C:\DevTools\QuantLib-1.3\lib`, what should I do to make something like the code below to work properly if called from `R`?

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double timesTwo(double x) {
  QuantLib::Calendar myCal = QuantLib::UnitedKingdom();
  QuantLib::Date newYearsEve(31, QuantLib::Dec, 2008);
  QuantLib::Rate zc3mQuote = x;
  return zc3mQuote * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the Rcpp FAQ for the general question of 'can I use R and Rcpp with Visual Studio' (tl;dr: No, you can't).

But before there was Rcpp there was already RQuantLib, and it still exists.  Download its sources, download the quantlib-1.4.zip from [the 'extras' site in Oxford](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html) and just rebuild RQuantLib with it. Which uses Rcpp.

You can then extend RQuantLib to your heart's content.

The newest RQuantLib also has a plugin similar to what RcppArmadillo and RcppEigen have, so you can build the quick little test files like the one you posted.  I will try to follow-up on the weekend with an existence proof example.

***Edit*:** As promised, I gave that a go. With the current RQuantLib (0.3.12) and Rcpp (0.11.1, released today but 0.11.0 should work) and your file save in `/tmp/lisaann.cpp` this "just works":

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/lisaann.cpp")
R> timesTwo(1.23)
[1] 2.46
R>
```

If it fails for you on Windows, make sure have

- Rtools installed
- the pre-build QuantLib for use by R (see [my recent blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2014/03/11#quantlib-1.4-packages))
- have the environment variables set which `src/Makevars.win` expects

Else, just use Ubuntu, Debian, or any other sane OS in a virtual machine.

***Edit 2:*** One important part, though, is that the `[[ Rcpp::depends() ]]` attribute is added to your code.  With that, here is the file I used:

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RQuantLib)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double timesTwo(double x) {
  QuantLib::Calendar myCal = QuantLib::UnitedKingdom();
  QuantLib::Date newYearsEve(31, QuantLib::Dec, 2008);
  QuantLib::Rate zc3mQuote = x;
  return zc3mQuote * 2;
}
```

which differs from yours only in the (important!) reference to the plugin used here.