# Using the latest QuantLib code using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, macos, rcpp, quantlib

I have been hoping to reuse date and calendar functions in QuantLib in my R code. Since RQuantLib does not cover all calendars I have compiled and installed the latest QuantLib version. However I fail to run the example provided in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414198/calling-quantlib-from-r-through-rcpp). How do I configure Rcpp to properly compile and use the C++ code below?

I have tried to run the following code (in the file "myCode.cpp") using the Rcpp function sourceCpp("myCode.cpp"):

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RQuantLib)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double timesTwo(double x) {
  QuantLib::Calendar myCal = QuantLib::UnitedKingdom();
  QuantLib::Date newYearsEve(31, QuantLib::Dec, 2008);
  QuantLib::Rate zc3mQuote = x;
  return zc3mQuote * 2;
}
```

This results on the following errors:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_65848.so] Error 1
```

Things work fine when compiling the file "myCode.cpp" on the command line using the following command:

```
g++ -I/opt/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/boost \
-I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG \
-I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include  -I/usr/local/include  \
-I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" \
-I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RQuantLib/include"    \
-fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c QuantLibTest2.cpp -o QuantLibTest2.o \
-L/opt/local/lib/ -lQuantLib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the CRAN sources, or what is at GitHub?

It looks like the "Not Windows" branch in the setup needs some work.  It currently does

```
## on Linux and OS X, see if we have quantlib-config which may well be
## false in the case of prebuild binary packages as eg r-cran-rquantlib
## on Debian / Ubuntu as well as the OS X package from CRAN
qc <- system("bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config'", ignore.stderr=TRUE, intern=TRUE)
if (is.character(qc) && nchar(qc) > 1) {
    qlcflags <- system(paste(qc, "--cflags"), intern = TRUE)
    qllibs   <- system(paste(qc, "--libs"),   intern = TRUE)
}
```

Is `quantlib-config` in your PATH, and does it return the correct values?

I enabled / expanded support for what you want to do -- use RQuantLib via a Rcpp plugin -- in the last few days, so please try the current GitHub sources.  They work fine on Linux, but I don't have an OS X system to test on.

**Edit:** Thanks for accepting the answer. For completeness, your original code works *as-is* on my box using RQuantLib from GitHub sources:

```
R> system("cat /tmp/rql.cpp") 

#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h> 

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RQuantLib)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double timesTwo(double x) {
  QuantLib::Calendar myCal = QuantLib::UnitedKingdom();
  QuantLib::Date newYearsEve(31, QuantLib::Dec, 2008);
  QuantLib::Rate zc3mQuote = x;
  return zc3mQuote * 2;
}
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/rql.cpp")     # takes a few seconds
R> timesTwo(21)
[1] 42
R>
```

Comment: Wow, fast response! The error is on CRAN binary, should I have used sources? Am trying the GitHub SOURCES now. quantlib-config is in my current path.

Comment: Yes please.  For something like this you almost always need sources.  Michele and I are making a few changes these days, so why don't you join us on rquantlib-devel (which is a pretty quiet list).

Comment: I installed from CRAN and GitHub but the same error turns up. Is this a problem with RQuantLib or with Rccp? Will have a look the the mailing list later this week when finished my current work on 30/360 and US calendar counting.

Comment: I cannot tell from the info you supplied, and I don't have time to dig right now.  Can you see if a simple file like `unitTests/cpp/dates.cpp` works for you via `sourceCpp()`?

Comment: If we are talking about the quantlib one, no the dates.cpp does not work. I will try to look into it late this week. I Have sent attempt to subscribe to mailing list for further discussion, time permitting.

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve this. It still fails on my mac 10.9.x, but I might give it a try later this week when I deploy to my Linux environment. I am just hoping its mac for the time being and may revert back on the list if the issue re-emerges.